# Issue with opening sqlite database file

Tags: php, database, sqlite

I am trying to make use of sqlite for the first time, now I have used this :

```
$this->linkIdentifier = new SQLiteDatabase($database);
```

and it created a database just fine as website.sqlite opening it again doesn't give any problem but as soon as I use http://code.google.com/p/phpliteadmin/ to create a table and I try to open it again it gives me this error : file is encrypted or is not a database

What could be causing this ?

Comment: Permissions issue maybe? Check that the permissions are the same before using phpliteadmin as after. Also if this is a local environment i recommend the Air app [Lita](http://www.dehats.com/drupal/?q=node/58). Ive never been a fan of web interfaces :-)

Answer (score 1):

Just for clarification: There are SQLite database-files of version 2 and version 3. With "new SQLiteDatabase()", you create a db-file of version 2. With "new SQLite3()" you create a file of version 3.
PhpLiteAdmin has support for both versions if the appropriate php extension is installed. PhpLiteAdmin tells you the extension being used when you open the "structure" tab of the database under "SQLite extension". It should say "SQLiteDatabase" there if you open a version 2 database. If it does not, e.g. because this extension is not installed, you might not be able to edit a version 2 database in phpLiteAdmin.
The SQLiteDatabase extension might not be included in recent versions of PHP, e.g. in PHP 5.4, it is only available via PECL.

Comment: First place I've found an explanation that sqlite databases can have different versions that are not compatible with one and another. Makes sense why everything I try with a new installation of PHP I can't open my, probably, version 2 database.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use PHP's own [SQLite3 functions](http://de.php.net/manual/en/sqlite3.construct.php) to create and save a database. Make sure to set the `SQLITE3_OPEN_CREATE` flag.

Comment: Going to try that now, but what do you mean with the SQLITE3_OPEN_CREATE flag ?

Comment: `SQLite3::__construct ( string $filename [, int $flags [, string $encryption_key ]] )` - the flags parameter needs to contain `SQLITE3_OPEN_CREATE`. I just see:  "By default, open uses SQLITE3_OPEN_READWRITE | SQLITE3_OPEN_CREATE.", which is fine for you.